# Scroll NSTableView to endOfDocument not the last row

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsscrollview

I have `NSTableView` with dynamic row heights. I need to scroll to the end. I tried `scrollToEndOfDocument:` but it gives same result as `scrollRowToVisible:` which is start of last row

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[[self tableView] scrollRowToVisible:[[self tableView] numberOfRows] - 1];
    [[self tableView] scrollToEndOfDocument:self];
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: What is "the end"? Did you try `scrollColumnToVisible(_:)` or `scrollToVisible(_:)`?

Comment: scrollRowToVisible is in the commented code (look up). Any difference with column?  All scroll to the start of row/column. PS: End is the true end of documentView. However this shouldn't be calculated if one has 1 000 000 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scrollRowToVisible` approach should work. Here's a quick [sample project](https://github.com/seanmrich/TableScroll) that implements variable heights with a button that scrolls to the last row. That last row is fully visible after scrolling.

[image: TableScroll image]

Update:
For table cells larger than the surrounding NSClipView, the above technique will only scroll to the top of the cell. To scroll to the bottom of the last cell, you can use:

```
let point = NSPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.frame.height)
tableView.scroll(point)
```

or since OP was in ObjC:

```
[[self tableView] scrollPoint: NSMakePoint(0, [self tableView].frame.size.height)]
```

Comment: But my row is larger than clipview. Would love to see your result if you set rowHeight to 500

Comment: In that case, try using NSView's scrollToVisible(_: NSRect). Measure out the bottom portion of the last row and use that as the rect to scroll to.

Comment: Isn't that is CAScrollLayer method? I don't see it on NSTableView/NSResponder.

Comment: It's an NSView method: [scrollToVisible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483811-scrolltovisible)

Comment: [[self tableView] scrollPoint:NSMakePoint([self tableView].frame.size.width, [self tableView].frame.size.height)]; Please update with this and I upvote. Thanks.